# Why is part of speech tagging is closely related to word sense disambiguation?

Tags: computational-linguistics

It's written here [Word Sense Disambiguation: A Structured Learning Perspective](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6327/6239d754c9f5c13688d51193d08d71a3c1c9.pdf):

> 2.1 Basics of Word Sense Disambiguation
>
> ...the POS is usually provided before WSD. **POS tagging is closely related to WSD**, and POS tagging is a well-studied problem with accuracy over 95%, thus the separation of POS tagging from WSD can fully expose the hardest core of WSD.

The best explanation for the proposition in boldface inside the blockquote I could find on google is the following picture on book [Neural Representations of Natural Language](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=tBxrDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Neural+Representations+of+Natural+Language&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK69-GvZnjAhWLJLkGHfpABRcQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=Neural%20Representations%20of%20Natural%20Language&f=false):

[image]

Nonetheless, that book explain the relationship between POS tagging and other word sense problems and not to Word Sense Disambiguation.

Please, explain the relationship between POS (part-of-speech) tagging and WSD (word sense disambiguation).

Comment: What exactly needs "better explanation"? What is it exactly you're trying to understand/do? Please try to formulate a clear _question_, a general request to explain something is pointless if we don't know what you want to do with it.

Comment: What do you mean by "the phrases inside blockquotes"? If it means "the proposition in boldface insides the blockquote", i.e, "POS tagging is closely related to WSD", please clarify in the question. Please note the meaning of ["a phrase"](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/phrase) is "an expression consisting of one or more words forming a grammatical constituent of a sentence" that **"can't stand alone"**.

Comment: I just took the liberty to edit the question. @Ricardo, please correct as you see fit.

Comment: @Ricardo, it looks like you just want some explanation since no explicit explanation can be found at all. Please confirm or clarify.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, an explicit explanation, @Apass.Jack